# Netsuite - add custom field to Purchase Order

Tags: netsuite

Hi I want to add a custom field to NetSuite. Please guide me how to do this. NetSuite has lack of Documentation.

I tried adding a `New Body Field` and `New Column Field`, none of them  add that value to the interface.

Please help me on

1. How to add a custom field
2. how to link that custom field to Purchase Order Object.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have created the field, but haven't assigned the field to a record type. Click the Applies To subtab and check the boxes of the records where you want the field to display.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: In the NetSuite Help Table of Contents, choose SuiteCloud, then SuiteBuilder, then Custom Fields. It will walk you through all the steps. Are you doing all these steps?

Or look in SuiteAnswers at ID # 10078.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Transaction body field under 
`customization > List, Record & Field > Transaction Body Fields > New` 
then on the on Applies To tab you can check `Purchase` and on the `Display` tab you can set the subtab where you want that custom field to be displayed. for example say `main` tab.

Hope this will help you setting up your custom field :)